# Sinatra(Ruby) app does not transfer mp4 files correctly

Tags: ruby, html, sinatra

I got my routing here:

```
get "/fortytwo" do
  send_file("42.mp4")
end
```

And my HTML for the page that shall play the video is as follows:

```
<body>
    <video controls autoplay>
        <source src="fortytwo" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
```

But when loading the page, a disabled video player shows up that won't play any media. Linking to a copy of the video that was uploaded to Dropbox with "dl=1" works perfectly fine.

Comment: what happens when you navigate directly to /fortytwo?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37570158/295671

Comment: it's the same. a simple disabled video player that refuses to play anything.

Comment: @james246 tried to patch it using your solution, but still does not work. any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is working fine, so the problem must be somewhere else than in Sinatra. Maybe a [CORS problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working), where is your HTML file located? It should be on the same domain where Sinatra is running.

I remade the whole program (below) and it's working:

```
require 'sinatra'

get "/fortytwo" do
  send_file("42.mp4")
end

get "/" do
  page = <<-endfile
  <body>
  <video controls autoplay>
  <source src="fortytwo" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  </body>
  endfile
end
```